# What is SYSTAG.BIN on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I have a file named `SYSTAG.BIN` in my operating system root folder - what is it? is it safe to delete it?

(couldn't find info about it on google)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file SYSTAG.BIN is created by AOEMEI Backupper, a free backup tool for Windows.
I had installed "AOMEI Backupper Standard Edition 2.0.2" recently and noticed this file created.
This file appears to be used to uniquely tag a system for its System Backup functionality.

```
The copy found on a system contains mostly zeros.
There was a 32 bit int at 0x004 and this was repeated at 0x200.
```

An additional 2 bytes were non-zero at 0x209 and 0x20A (assumption of bytes due to alignment).

The file size was 0x400 bytes.

```
My file had hashes:
 File: SYSTAG.BIN
CRC-32: b12606aa
   MD4: b137ac9768f55bb26fb34812bdb5febe
   MD5: ec528ffc0334ee95494e8d31763ccf7d
 SHA-1: bee535bf535d322512d42ed304bb268b17766553
```

It is highly unlikely that the readers copy of this file will match, as each file is a uniquely system tag as the filename would indicate.

As this was a top entry for the search string "SYSTAG.BIN".
I hope this comes in useful to someone!

Comment: So if I delete this file would I have any problem when I want to perform a system restore from a AOMEI backup file? Can it be deleted safely?

Comment: b.t.w I has also a AMTAG.BIN  file created by AOEMEI Backupper at the root of the OS drive.

Comment: `AMTAG.BIN` should be from _AOMEI Partition Assistant_ [AOMEI forum](https://www.aomeitech.com/forum/discussion/1610/necessarity-and-turn-off-creation-of-systag-bin-and-amtag-bin)